# since last package upgrade dark screen with gdm3 on nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, gnome, 22.04, xorg

Lost in logs and install/removal, can't find where to look further.
since the last generic upgrade and reboot I get a 'dark' screen as a greeter.
Locally I can't use the system however remote services SSH/minidlna works fine, but I use the system locally too.

I used to be able to get to the TTY with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F3</kbd>/<kbd>F4</kbd>..., now I touched  so many things I just get a blinking cursor starting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
And a "no signal / power-off screen" with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>

running

```
nvidia-driver-535 - distro non-free recommended
# nvidia-smi
Sat Feb  3 22:17:12 2024
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 535.154.05             Driver Version: 535.154.05   CUDA Version: 12.2     |
|-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name                 Persistence-M | Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp   Perf          Pwr:Usage/Cap |         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                                         |                      |               MIG M. |
|=========================================+======================+======================|
|   0  NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070        Off | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 33%   25C    P8              11W / 190W |     15MiB /  8192MiB |      0%      Default |
|                                         |                      |                  N/A |
+-----------------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                            |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                            GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                             Usage      |
|=======================================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1657      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            8MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1795      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                          3MiB |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The only error for Xorg is removed drivers :

```
grep EE /var/log/Xorg.0.log
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     8.348] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[     8.349] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[     8.349] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[     8.574] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[     8.575] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[     8.575] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[     9.617] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
```

X and gdl3 runs :

```
ps -elf | grep Xorg
4 S root        1657    1655  0  80   0 - 6349510 ep_pol 22:07 tty1   00:00:03 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt1 -displayfd 3 -auth /run/user/121/gdm/Xauthority -nolisten tcp -background none -noreset -keeptty -novtswitch -verbose 3

# systemctl status gdm3
● gdm.service - GNOME Display Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gdm.service; static)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2024-02-03 22:07:35 CET; 14min ago
    Process: 1611 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/gdm/generate-config (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 1616 (gdm3)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 28663)
     Memory: 5.9M
        CPU: 95ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/gdm.service
             └─1616 /usr/sbin/gdm3

févr. 03 22:07:35 merisier systemd[1]: Starting GNOME Display Manager...
févr. 03 22:07:35 merisier systemd[1]: Started GNOME Display Manager.
févr. 03 22:07:35 merisier gdm-launch-environment][1621]: pam_unix(gdm-launch-environment:session): session opened for user gdm(uid=121) by (uid=0)
```

No control all black where shall I look?

Update for DanielT:
on ssh (remember no more tty)

```
root@merisier:/# systemctl stop gdm3
root@merisier:/# pgrep xorg
root@merisier:/# startx
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux merisier 5.15.0-92-generic #102-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 10 09:33:48 UTC 2024 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-92-generic root=UUID=d4bd3303-35a5-4bf1-9b76-55a739d843ba ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.8 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support)
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Feb  4 10:41:24 2024
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(II) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen: type not specified, assuming 'stylus'.
(II) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen: other types will be automatically added.
(--) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen stylus: using pressure threshold of 851 for button 1
(**) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen stylus: panscroll is 0
(**) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen stylus: panscroll modified to 1040
(--) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen stylus: maxX=10206 maxY=7422 maxZ=511 resX=80000 resY=80000  tilt=disabled
(II) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen stylus: hotplugging dependent devices.
(II) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen stylus: hotplugging completed.
(**) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen eraser: panscroll is 1040
(**) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen eraser: panscroll modified to 1040
(--) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen eraser: maxX=10206 maxY=7422 maxZ=511 resX=80000 resY=80000  tilt=disabled
(**) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen cursor: panscroll is 1040
(**) wacom: Wacom Graphire2 4x5 Pen cursor: panscroll modified to 1040
```

Then nothing else, I do have a graphire2 plugged in.
So I <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
^Cxinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.

xinit: unexpected signal 2
root@merisier:/# grep EE "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 45236.911] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 45236.913] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 45236.913] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 45237.197] (EE) Failed to load module "nouveau" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 45237.198] (EE) Failed to load module "fbdev" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 45237.198] (EE) Failed to load module "vesa" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 45237.668] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
root@merisier:/# grep WW "/var/log/Xorg.0.log"
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[ 45236.252] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[ 45236.252] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[ 45236.252] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[ 45236.252] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[ 45236.252] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[ 45236.911] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
[ 45236.913] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[ 45236.913] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[ 45237.197] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module nouveau
[ 45237.198] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module fbdev
[ 45237.198] (WW) Warning, couldn't open module vesa
[ 45237.221] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[ 45237.622] (WW) NVIDIA(0): Unable to get display device for DPI computation.
```

I'll contact http://www.ubuntu.com/support... and let know up comes.
In mean time any hint welcome

Comment: Does `startx` in the TTY show anything?

Comment: Please [edit] your post because comments will truncate logs and remove formatting

Comment: @DanielT, i updated the question whit the test you asked

Comment: I'm sorry. If the TTY isn't working, then that's a far more fundamental problem, and I don't know how to continue. The last "generic upgrade" must have installed the wrong packages or broken/disabled a critical service (getty@tty1). I only know to suggest a reinstall.

Comment: @DanielT update If x not working 1st tty is blinking cursor, others are OK, so tty not lost.
if X is started, switching fom the no signal screen to the other tty is "long", i was impatient, may be because the screen need to power up.
Startx on console tty3 give same messages as on ssh.

Comment: If you insist on starting X from SSH, you need to tell it which tty to use. Run `sudo bash -c 'startx <>/dev/tty3'` while you have tty3 open

Answer (score 1):

following intuition of HW issue :

1. No logical error with physical dark screen no signal.
2. 7 year old MSI card with suspicion too tight calculated component.

I booted on a usbkey and the graphical boot would end the same, when frame buffer would work.

Finally swapped from dvi-d plugs and cable to hdmi and tadaaa all OK.
I agree I'm lucky, the fault could be earlier in the pipe.

My dark screen is Harware Defective caused.
Issue is worked around, fix will require some financial efforts.